# How to blend / mask videos in AVFoundation?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, merge, avfoundation

I have `n` videos i want to merge in one larger video. I am doing this with AVFoundation (`AVMutableComposition` and `AVAssetExportSession`). Actually my prototype is adding the videos one after another – without blending. But I would like to add some blending (fade) or even better a masking transition.

Is it possible with AVFoundation to fade the videos? Is it even possible to mask the videos and transform/animate the mask? It would be nice if someone can leave a keyword to search for.

Answer (score 1):

Reading the docs will help:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/03_Editing.html

As you can see, what you're looking for is [AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avmutablevideocompositionlayerinstruction).